# Mouse Move Handle on a ListBox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox on which I want to handle the mousemove event; And for that reason I'm using the following code

```
Private Sub AreaLB_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles AreaLB.MouseMove
        Dim ListMousePosition As Point = AreaLB.PointToClient(Me.MousePosition)
        Dim itemIndex As Integer = AreaLB.IndexFromPoint(ListMousePosition)
        Dim AreaToolTip As ToolTip = ToolTip1
        Dim myLB As ListBox = AreaLB
        AreaToolTip.Active = True
        Dim g As Graphics = AreaLB.CreateGraphics()
        If itemIndex > -1 Then
            Dim s As String = myLB.Items(itemIndex)
            If g.MeasureString(s, myLB.Font).Width > myLB.ClientRectangle.Width Then
                AreaToolTip.SetToolTip(myLB, s)
            Else
                AreaToolTip.SetToolTip(myLB, "")
            End If
            g.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
```

My problem is... When I'm not moving the mouse this procedure runs always when the
`g.MeasureString(s, myLB.Font).Width > myLB.ClientRectangle.Width`
Why that happens and how can I avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is only set the ToolTip if it isn't already the value you want it to be:

```
Private Sub AreaLB_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles AreaLB.MouseMove
    ToolTip1.Active = True
    Dim itemIndex As Integer = AreaLB.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)
    If itemIndex > -1 Then
        Using g As Graphics = AreaLB.CreateGraphics()
            Dim s As String = AreaLB.Items(itemIndex)
            If g.MeasureString(s, AreaLB.Font).Width > AreaLB.ClientRectangle.Width Then
                If ToolTip1.GetToolTip(AreaLB) <> s Then
                    ToolTip1.Show(s, AreaLB)
                End If
            Else
                ToolTip1.Show("", AreaLB)
            End If
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```